# JPA: How to override the column name of a nested @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

#### Project description

I use **Spring Boot 3.2.3** with **Kotlin**, **Gradle - Kotlin** and **Java 21**.
I use **Postgres** as my db.

#### The actual problem

In the code below I created a simple *OneToMany* relationship between `Company` and `Employee`.
The **ID** of the employee is `EmployeeId`, which itself contains `CompanyId` and `employeeName`.

```kotlin
@Embeddable
data class CompanyId(
    val companyId: Long,
)

@Entity
data class Company(
    @EmbeddedId
    val companyId: CompanyId,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    val employees: List<Employee> = emptyList(),
)

@Embeddable
data class EmployeeId(
    @Embedded
    val companyId: CompanyId,
    val employeeName: String,
)

@Entity
data class Employee(
    @EmbeddedId
    val employeeId: EmployeeId,
    @MapsId("companyId") @ManyToOne
    val company: Company,
)
```

When I run the project the generated columns for `Employee` are `company_company_id` and `name` but I'd rather have `company_company_id` be overwritten to `company_id`.

The picture below shows again the generated columns
[image: employee entity column names]

#### What I tried

I tried using `@AttributeOverride`

```kotlin
@Embeddable
data class EmployeeId(
    @Embedded
    val companyId: CompanyId,
    val employeeName: String,
)

@Entity
data class Employee(
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "companyId.companyId", column = Column(name = "id"))
    val employeeId: EmployeeId,
    @MapsId("companyId") @ManyToOne
    val company: Company,
)
```

#### My question

How can I override the column names generated for `EmployeeId`?

Comment: Interesting. Apart from using `EmbeddedId` instead of `Embedded`, this looks very similar to example 2 on https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/persistence/attributeoverride. Could it be that this doesn't work for `EmbeddedId`?

Comment: How about adding the override to `EmployeeId` instead?

Comment: You could also try to override the column in additional xml `entity-mappings` declarations for your persistence unit.

Comment: what is also weird is that it works to change the column name for employeeName but for companyId it doesn't

Comment: I thinks it is from `@MapsId` because I used `@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)` and now it works just fine.